Integrating AdMob with Google's AdManager in Android Kotlin App Using Waterfalling Approach
I'm developing an Android application using Kotlin, and I want to integrate both Google AdManager and AdMob to maximize ad revenue. My goal is to use a waterfalling approach, where an AdManager banner ad is attempted first, and if it fails to load or does not return an ad, I then attempt to load an AdMob ad in the same ad space. Here is my implementation so far:
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

 private lateinit var adManagerAdView: AdManagerAdView
 private lateinit var adMobAdView: AdView

 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

     // Initialize the AdManager AdView
     adManagerAdView = findViewById(R.id.adManagerAdView)
     val adManagerRequest = AdManagerAdRequest.Builder().build()
     adManagerAdView.loadAd(adManagerRequest)
     
     // Set up a listener for AdManager ad events
     adManagerAdView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
         override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
             // AdManager failed to load an ad, try AdMob
             loadAdMobAd()
         }

         override fun onAdLoaded() {
             // AdManager ad loaded successfully
         }
     }
 }

 private fun loadAdMobAd() {
     // Initialize the AdMob AdView
     adMobAdView = findViewById(R.id.adMobAdView)
     val adMobRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
     adMobAdView.loadAd(adMobRequest)

     // Set up a listener for AdMob ad events
     adMobAdView.adListener = object : AdListener() {
         override fun onAdFailedToLoad(error: LoadAdError) {
             // AdMob failed to load an ad, handle the failure
         }

         override fun onAdLoaded() {
             // AdMob ad loaded successfully
         }
     }
 }
}


In my layout file (activity_main.xml), I have included both AdManager and AdMob AdViews:
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.admanager.AdManagerAdView
        android:id="@+id/adManagerAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="AD_MANAGER_AD_UNIT_ID" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adMobAdView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ADMOB_AD_UNIT_ID"
        android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>


I have a few questions regarding this implementation:
Policy Compliance: Is this waterfalling approach compliant with Google AdMob and AdManager policies? I want to ensure that my app will not be penalized for this setup.
Visibility Handling: Currently, I set the AdMob AdView visibility to gone in the XML layout. Should I programmatically handle the visibility of the AdMob AdView only when the AdManager ad fails to load?
Best Practices: Are there any best practices or potential pitfalls I should be aware of when integrating both AdManager and AdMob in this manner?
Any advice or guidance on these questions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Just making sure you've seen: https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/9234653?hl=en
